# Gradle - Pulling resources from github rep

Tags: github, gradle

I am trying to pull the following github rep as a dependency:
https://github.com/bft-smart/library

this is my gradle file:

```
group '1.0'
version '0.1-Setup'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.github.bft-smart:library:master-SNAPSHOT'

}
```

But I get: Unable to resolve com.github.bft-smart:library:master-SNAPSHOT.

Thanks already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jitpack does not currently support ant projects. See [here](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/127).

Comment: And is there another way to get github projects?

Comment: You can build it yourself and publish the binaries to a local (or if you really want to, a public) repository